# How to pass edittext value from android to java RESTFUL webservice url

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Android, I'm using a Java RESTful webservice for login purposes..

Webservice url:
http://localhost:8084/TestWebApp/webresources/userbay/signin?mobile=username&code=password

Here username and password are from Edittext values from Android.

My question is, how to pass the EditText value from Android to that webservice URL, and how to get the response from the webservice store to an Android variable.

My code:

```js
public void btnClick(View v)
    {
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signin_mobile);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signin_password);
        String usrname = username.getText().toString();
        String usrpassword = password.getText().toString();
        if (usrname.equals("") || usrpassword.equals("") ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field cannot be left blank.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else {
            webservice();
        }

    }
```

I don't know how to start to connect to the webservice.. a code sample would be most helpful for me..

Comment: Just do a google search.

Comment: look at retrofit library http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I done in webservice coding.. its working perfect.. But i dont know how to coonect to android.

Comment: http://www.go4expert.com/articles/step-step-guide-sending-data-android-t30182/        Check this link @Appu

Comment: learn how work http request and response. After that use Volley Library

Answer (score 0):

follow the link 
http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-call-restful-webservice-in-android-part-3/

it will help u :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use **Spring for Android** in you Android project.

Spring offers **RestTemplate** that allows you to send HTTP requests to RESTful services and retrieve result data. Both request and response can be transported in JSON format. With **RestTemplate** you just send and retrieve Java object.

You can learn more here:
http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use **Volley**. Some time ago, the Google+ team did a series of performance tests on each of the different methods you can use to make **network requests** on Android. Volley got a score up to **ten times** better than the other alternatives when used in RESTful applications.

Volley is a networking library developed by Google and introduced during Google I/O 2013.

Searching on Google you'll find a lot of examples on how to use:

[Example 1](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800)

[Example 2](http://blog.chrisblunt.com/android-getting-started-with-volley/)

[Example 3](http://androidsrc.net/android-volley-library-tutorial/)